# Custom form control from external assembly

Tags: asp.net, controls, .net-assembly, libraries, kentico

Ultimately I'm trying to build a control that will let my users specify in which order their fields will appear on the page. So I'm building a custom form control to solve it.

I'm having a problem with my web user controls not getting initialized when loaded from an assembly. I have the following code:

**FieldOrder.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FieldOrder.ascx.cs" Inherits="Sologic.Website.Admin.Controls.FieldOrder" %>

<asp:ListBox ID="fieldList" runat="server" />
```

**FieldOrder.ascx.cs:**

```
public partial class FieldOrder : FormEngineUserControl
{
    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return "1";
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var className = DocumentManager.Node.ClassName;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
            className = DocumentManager.NewNodeClassName;

        ClassStructureInfo.GetColumns(className).ForEach(cn => fieldList.Items.Add(cn));
    }
}
```

This all gets bundled into an assembly, that is then placed into the Kentico bin/ folder. Finally I registered it with Kentico: [image: form control editor]

Unfortunately I'm getting:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sologic.Website.Admin.Controls.FieldOrder.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +102
   CMS.Base.Web.UI.AbstractUserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1380
```

When I attach to the w3wp process I can see my control is null. When I run this same control in a normal web app scenario it is not null. When I run this same code as a Web User Control it appears to work just fine. Is there some kind of initialization code that needs to be run when loading controls via DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Try set [[assembly:CMS.AssemblyDiscoverable]](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/customizing-providers/registering-providers-using-assembly-attributes)